# Get user details from end of OAuth2 Flow

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth

I'm unsure how to get the uses details after successfully oauth2 flow.

Code:

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(...
...

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
self.redirect(str(auth_uri))
....

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
# credentials prints empty string
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `str()` on the `auth_uri`? There should be no need to do that. What is `code` in this example?

Comment: @bernie str is just a habbit with urls red. code is just '?code=sadasads'

Comment: Have you tried it out here: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ ?